# How to select child which may have multi kind of parent ?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select `myclass` , whose parent may be `parent1 or parent2`

I may write this :

```
div .parent1 .myclass{

}

div .parent2 .myclass{

}
```

How can I make two selections into one ?

such as:

```
div `.parent1 {or} .parent2` .myclass{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you can write like this:

```
div .myclass{}
```

or

```
.myclass{}
```

or

```
div .parent1 .myclass, div .parent2 .myclass{}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent1 .myclass, .parent2 .myclass{}
```

Comment: Is there any way that I could write `myclass` only once ?